# Nylas N1 plugin that opens a web page in a Nylas Window

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs, flux, electron

Been looking through the [Nylas Docs](http://nylas.github.io/N1/docs/) but didn't see a way to create a plugin that opens a website in a new Nylas window. I'd like to create a plugin that simply is a Nylas window pointing to a URL, any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Maggew Dot Com, I'm the coauthor of the N1 unsubscribe plugin. Here is the code you want to use to open a browser window:

```
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow;
const url = 'https://github.com';

const browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    web-preferences: { 'web-security': false },
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    center: true,
});

browserWindow.on('closed', () => {
    callback(null, true);
});

// // Useful for development and monitoring action of browserWindow
// // Especially since N1 doesn't allow injecting a custom script
// browserWindow.on('page-title-updated', function(event) {
//    webContents = browserWindow.webContents;
//    if (!webContents.isDevToolsOpened()) {
//        webContents.openDevTools();
//    }
// });

browserWindow.loadURL(url);
browserWindow.show();
```

If you want to learn more, see the [Electron - Browser Window](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) documentation

Answer (score 0):

Dig into the code provided by the [N1 Unsubscribe Plugin](https://github.com/colinking/n1-unsubscribe) you'll notice they integrate that option by default when you click the icon to unsub.

https://github.com/colinking/n1-unsubscribe#settings

**use_browser**